# Mongo DB average values

Tags: mongodb

I have collection with values stored in arrays like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e7740b6d2263f72d3fada2a"), "values" : [ 2, 2, 2, 5, 2, 2, 4, 5 ] }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e7740b6d2263f72d3fada27"),  "values" : [ 4, 5, 5, 5, 2, 5, 2, 5 ] }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e7740b6d2263f72d3fada29"),  "values" : [ 5, 5, 3, 2, 2, 2, 4, 5 ] }
```

I tried following:

```
db.collection.aggregate([ { $project: { avg: { $avg: "$values"} } } ])
```

I get this result:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e773f87d2263f72d3fada26"), "avg" : 3.625 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e7740b6d2263f72d3fada27"), "avg" : 4.125 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e7740b6d2263f72d3fada28"), "avg" : 3.75 }
```

Instead of above I would like to get one average value for all: for example 3.895

Comment: What have you tried? Example from MongoDB [$avg](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/) docs is descriptive and contains examples

Comment: Hi, thank you for answer. I tried following:
db.collection.aggregate([    { $project: { avg: { $avg: "$values"} } } ])
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e773f87d2263f72d3fada26"), "avg" : 3.625 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e7740b6d2263f72d3fada27"), "avg" : 4.125 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e7740b6d2263f72d3fada28"), "avg" : 3.75 }

Instead of above I would like to get one average value for all: for example 3.895

Comment: Please edit your question to add the code instead of putting it into a comment.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the average of all values use this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $unwind: "$values" },
   {
      $group: {
         _id: null,
         avg: { $avg: "$values" }
      }
   }
])
```

If you like to get the average of the averages then use

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $project: { avg: { $avg: "$values" } } },
   {
      $group: {
         _id: null,
         avg: { $avg: "$avg" }
      }
   }
])
```